# For each element in the array find the number of ways to present it as a sum of two other numbers from this array

Tags: binary-search

You are given the size of an array and the array itself. I know this problem can be solved effectively with the use of the binary search idea, but i don't know how to use it here. Would appreciate any help and code in c++ or python.

Here is the input-output example:

input:

```
5 
3 3 2 2 1
```

output:

```
2 2 0 0 0
```

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm from Russia and I'm 16

Comment: Didnt understand how are you getting this output?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal first 3 can be presented as (first 2 + 1) and as (second 2 + 1), same for second 3, 2 and 1 cannot be presented as sum of other numbers in this array

Comment: Give more input/output example, it help other users to better understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it is not the exact output you want, but is very close:

```
import itertools
count =[]
stuff = [3,3,2,2,1]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        if len(subset) ==2:
            add = sum(subset)
            count.append(len([i for i in stuff if i == add]))
            print count
```